# A question about the relation between linear transformations and their representing matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

I would like to have some clarification regarding the notion that all linear transformations can be represented by "representing matrices". There's this lemma that the space of all linear transformations from spaces V to U are isomophic to m×n matrices (m being dimV and n being dimU). Which leads to my question: given a matrix m×n, can I deduce that there exists some transformation from V to U (dimV = m and dimU =n) that is represented by this very matrix (since isomophic relationships go both ways)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's right... though it seems your convention for matrix representations is different from what I'm used to. Lets say $V,U$ are vector spaces over a field $F$ of dimension $n,m$ respectively. Then, yes we can construct an isomorphism $L(V,U)\cong M_{m\times n}(F)$, but this isomorphism depends heavily on the choice of basis.

More explicitly, if $\beta$ is a basis of $V$, and $\gamma$ is a basis of $U$, then we can construct a linear isomorphism $\Phi_{\beta,\gamma}:L(V,U)\to M_{m\times n}(F)$. But, like I've indicated in the notation, the isomorphism $\Phi_{\beta,\gamma}$ very much depends on the basis $\beta,\gamma$. If you change the basis to a different one, say $\beta', \gamma'$, you will get a different isomorphism $\Phi_{\beta',\gamma'}$. So you always have to be careful when dealing with matrices and **always make sure to explicitly mention what the bases being used are.**

Comment: Why exactly can’t a non linear transformation be represented a matrix

Comment: @Shashaank because a non-linear function is not determined by its value on a basis, so it makes no sense to assign a matrix to it. For example, consider a function $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=1$. If I tell you nothing else, there's no way you can know what $f(2)$ is or more generally what $f(x)$ is for arbitrary $x$. But if I tell you the function is linear then immediately you can deduce that $f(x) =x$ for all x. Geometrically, if I give you a ooint in the plane $R^2$, there is a unique straight line through the origin and that point, but of course there are infinitely many curves.

Comment: could you please give an example of such a $T$ such that $T:(x, y) -> "something"$ and then show that we can represent $T$ in a matrix form by just calculation the action of $T$ on the basis vectors ( which is how we calculate the matrix representation of an operator) .  Such an example would help me to see exactly why the matrix representation for a non linear transformation is not possible. I mean an explicit example showing how the action of a non linear transformation can't be  used to write a matrix representation.

Comment: @Shashaank I'll give you $T(x,y)=(x^2,0)$. How about you tell me what the action on the basis $e_1=(1,0), e_2=(0,1)$ is and tell me why it doesn't work.

Comment: sure. So $T(1,0) = (1,0)= 1. e_1 + 0.e_2 $ and $T(0,1)=(0,0)= 0.e_1 + 0.e_2$. So the matrix representation of $T$ is - 1st column is (1,0) and the second column is (0,0), thereby a perfect matrix representation though it’s non linear.  Where am I wrong ?

Comment: just that it will give - read in matrix notation ( a 2 by 2 matrix multiplying a column vector) - $[T]_b [e_2]_b = [T]_b [0]_b$. But that is expected since the transformation is not linear but I don’t see why the matrix representation I have got is itself not valid at all.

Comment: @Shashaank ok so $[T]=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$. Now, using the actual formula $T(x,y)=(x^2,0)$ tell me what is  $T(2e_1)$ and then compare with $[T]\cdot [2e_1]$. What is the difference here?

Comment: ohh I see. The first one is (4,0) which in the basis representation would translate to a column vector (4,0) and the 2nd one is a colum vector (2,0). 2 different answers using 2 different ways, so the matrix representation is not working here. Am I correct? Is that what you wanted to show? If sho I think I get it now.

Comment: @Shashaank yes exactly; you're getting different answers precisely because $T$ is not linear.

Comment: yeah I see the point. I could still write a matrix representation for a non linear Transformation but it would be completely useless to do since it would give a different answer from what I would get directly from the transformation rule, suggesting that writing a matrix in the first place was the wrong thing to do. Many thanks for making it lucid...